# finding function by points Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have two list *x* and *y*. I combine them and receive list of point *{x,y}*. Using *ListLinPlot* I build a graphic. My question is - Can I find the function using points? I mean find formula/function *f(x)* if I know only points.
For an example :

*{{2,5},{3,7},{7,15},{9,19}}*

So the answer will be:

*F(x)=2x+1*

It was easy example, but my graphic is not a liner function. The blue line is my function. I changed picture that better describe the problem

[image]

Comment: y=x + 20 - 8/(1 + E^(5 (x - 25)))

Comment: @Bill well I'm not interesting on result, I'm interesting how to do it. How did you find it?

Comment: In general, the answer to your question is no, you cannot find THE arbitrary equation which happens to go through a set of data points. The SigmaPlot statistical software package used to try to do that, I don't know if it still does. How did I do it? I looked at your previous graph, from experience it looked like a line added to a sigmoid function. I tweaked the constants until it looked like it fit your original graph. You could probably do the same with your revised graph. Do you want to automate fitting that to your data? That will require more skill and trial and error with the Fit funtion

Comment: Well, there are a math chapter - approximation and interpolation.  And there is methods like, Lagrange polynomial, or Newton polynomial, so I looking how to using Mathematica realize it or other methods, build polynomial.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115444/2079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html

```
data = {{2, 5}, {3, 7}, {7, 15}, {9, 19}};
fit = FindFormula[data, x]
```

> ```
> 1. + 2. x
> ```